# Servicemix clustering example

Tags: esb, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Please suggest some good startup beginner examples for ServiceMix cluster setup. I understand here clustering is done by Karaf OSGI container using Karaf Cellar framework. But I couldn't find any step by step tutorial on this. I could set up ServiceMix and install camel based integration bundles. Not sure how to cluster 2 or more instances such ServiceMix with any one instance as management node.

Gone through links at 
[Clustering in ServiceMix 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907619/clustering-in-servicemix-4)

[How do I cluster ServiceMix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896074/how-do-i-cluster-servicemix)

but couldn't find ay concrete example for Karaf-Cellar clustering with SMX nodes
Please suggest if any step by step blog/guides explaining this

Thanks

Comment: I posted a comment on that 1st link about clustering in SMX pointing to an example how to cluster SMX using fabric8.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear step by step guide, but found similar for doing hands on

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/cellar/latest-2.2.x/user-guide/groups.html
http://karaf.apache.org/manual/cellar/latest-2.2.x/user-guide/introduction.html
http://blog.nanthrax.net/2011/07/apache-karaf-cellar-2-2-1-release/

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/child-instances.html

http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi-greeter-demo-walkthrough.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfNrTp371LA#t=153

And some good examples at,

http://kevinboone.net/osgitest.html

http://www.lucamasini.net/Home/osgi-with-felix/creating-osgi-bundles-of-your-maven-dependencies

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin/